# How to set the system loudness programmatically (on OSX and Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, macos, audio

I want to manipulate the system loudness (the global volume, or whatever it is called) from within my program. This might seem ridiculous, but I need to do some measurements, so I am interested in not only attenuating the sound via an internal loudness, but also amplify it, which is only possible using the system loudness. Since I am using Qt, a C++-solution would be greatly appreciated.

Would anyone know how to do this on either Windows or OSX? (Cross-platform development, you see...)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Am I gonna have to be the one to add this obligatory link? Really? (sigh) http://xkcd.com/530/

Comment: @gnovice Haha, I forgot that one! Great!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility on OSX is to use a terminal command:

```
#include <cstdlib>
system("osascript -e \"set Volume 5\"\n");
```

(Of course, you may change '`5`' to whatever you like; The range seems to be between 0 and about 7.5 (?))

Admittedly, this is not a pretty solution and I am still interested in a better one, but at least it works, although at a hefty performance cost while executing the command.